# How to deal with Python 2 cookies on a Python 3 Flask website?

Tags: python, cookies, flask

I upgraded my Flask website from Python 2 to Python 3. Now, users who have session cookies from the old Python 2 website see 500 errors, because Flask gives out an exception while processing the old Python 2 cookies. How can I clear this old cookies from users browsers so that they can see [my site](https://www.koipun.com)? The cookie is very simple e.g. `session=eyJfZnJlc2giOmZhbHNlLCJjc3JmX3Rva2VuIjoiN2UzOWEwNzM2YjljYzBkYzBjYjkzYWU0MzIyYjI3ODFmMzk0Nzk1YiJ9.C9_BRg.pP5na6ocIOjaE-jebwqjKZYkVDs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force a reset of the session for your users by updating your Flask `SECRET_KEY` value. This will invalidate client-side sessions when they next access the application.

This works because the Flask session is signed with the secret key - so when the key changes, the signature of the session cookie becomes invalid.